# Mosaico 1.1 - "Unexpected error talking to server" when saving template

Tags: drupal, mosaico

Just installed Mosaico 1.1 for CiviCRM 5.7.2 on Drupal 7.

Tried to make a dummy template and hit the save button but received an error saying "Unexpected error talking to server - contact us!" It then cleared the image that I had inserted there.

[image: screenshot of template clearing itself]

(I followed the steps of 1) installing shoreditch, 2) installing flexmailer, 3) installing mosaico)

Any ideas on what to do?

Have tried asking on the Mosaico github and contacting the developers but no luck.

Cheers,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using Mosaico 2.x for more than a year (currently Version 2.0-beta4) succesfully and without problems. I strongly recommend you use version 2. See [Mark Mosaico 2 stable](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/pull/286) for more info.

Comment: I'm now using Version 2.0-beta4 and although it solved this problem, it [created another](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28492/mosaico-2-0-drupal-7-64-sorry-an-error-occurred-and-your-information-was-not). Thanks for your help though! @Francesc Bassas i Bullich