# Mosaico 2.0, Drupal 7.64 - "Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved"

Tags: civimail, mosaico, custom-templates

Installed Mosaico 2.0-beta4 on Drupal 7.64 and CiviCRM 5.7.2. I followed all installation instructions and installed Shoreditch then Flexmailer then Mosaico.

I'm getting an error - when I try and edit a Mosaico template and drag a block in, it gives the error message of "Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved".

This happens whether I upload an image into a block, or just drag an empty text box and add dummy text, or anything in between.

[image]

This also happens regardless of which base template I'm trying to edit.

If I just try and create a new mail using the base templates, I can't preview the email as HTML or send out a test email (again, regardless of how much or how little I customise the base template) and get the same error message.

I've checked error logs and haven't found anything. All modules and core up to date, any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Thanks

EDIT: Some of the messages from Browser console. Not sure which of them are relevant:

```
The resource from “[default]/civicrm/css/?r=f1Bvs” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

.

```
Error while detaching the browsing context target front: Connection closed, pending request to server1.conn0.parentProcessTarget1, type detach failed
```

^ That one then has a "Request Stack" of around 20 lines.

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/favicon.ico (“default-src”).
```

.

```
Loading mixed (insecure) display content “http://mosaico.io/srv/f-default/img?method=placeholder&params=166%2C160” on a secure page[Learn More] jquery.min.js:4:19318

unreachable code after return statement
```

EDIT:

Checked the error log in cpanel, this is an error message we're getting at the same time:

```
2019-02-27 12:11:55.672900 [INFO] [203.166.241.141:58741-Q:2699717862144599633-5] File not found [/(homedirectory)/public_html/403.shtml]
```

Comment: Have you checked browser console?

Comment: @FrancescBassasiBullich I just checked browser console, have added some of the error messages into my post but not sure which one is responsible

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried asking your web host to see if you're throwing out a server based error, like a ModSecurity issue? I regularly run into those with CiviCRM when I'm doing emails and have to get the server techs to whitelist a process for me so that it doesn't give me an error. Other than a piece of bad formed code (like when someone has copied something from Word or whatever), it's always been this kind of issue for me.

Comment: Yea, my host was always able to pinpoint things in the logs that I wasn't seeing on my own. It's why now when this issue pops up, they're my first resource and they can quickly whitelist it.

Comment: thanks, I'll see if my host can whitelist whatever needs to be whitelisted. :)

Comment: Cool. I hope that is able to fix it for you. :)